# Does uncorrelated imply covariance is zero?

Tags: statistics

I know that if covariance is zero then x and y are uncorrelated but does uncorrelated also imply covariance is zero?

Comment: This is true... Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because

$$\text{Corr}(x,y)=\frac{\text{Cov}(x,y)}{\sqrt{V(x)V(y)}},$$

where $V$ is the variance.